# Php. Чтение файла с кириллицей

Tags: php, windows

Как прочитать содержимое файла с кириллицей в имени в Windows?
Пробовал след. варианты

```
file_get_contents("E:\\фото.jpg");
```

или

```
file_get_contents(mb_convert_encoding("E:\\фото.jpg", 'Windows-1251','UTF-8'));
```

Оба варианта выдают одну и туже ошибку

```
Warning: : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\file.php on line 2
```

Если переименовать в файл, например, в file.jpg, то чтение происходит успешно.

Comment: Файл поместите в доступную для сервера директорию.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS для имён файлов использует UTF 16. Значит пробуйте из кодировки вашего скрипта в UTF 16

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте минимальный необходимый пример реализации в ваш ответ, дополнив его ссылкой на источник. Согласно модели проекта, следует стремиться к самодостаточности публикуемых сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге прописать `php.ini`

```
[mbstring]
mbstring.language = utf-8
mbstring.internal_encoding = utf-8
mbstring.http_input = utf-8
mbstring.http_output = utf-8
```

В скрипте:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

Если это новое приложение, в котором не обязательно хранить файлы с оригинальными именами - я бы сделал транслитерацию, а если нужно оригинальное имя - хранить в базе.